# Git setup on mac (ERROR: "-bash: git: command not found")

Tags: eclipse, macos, git, github

I am trying to setup git on my Mac through this link (http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/).  I was successful until Step 5 and I do see the message `Hi kharagpur! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

When I try the next step ("Then: Setting Up Your info") I run into problems `-bash: git: command not found` when I tried to execute `git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"`

I am executing this line from the user/(myusername)/

My main goal is to setup github and pull projects from a repo to my local computer so I can code using Eclipse.

Any help appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you did not install git.

This worked for me (MacOSX Lion):

Get the installer:

```
curl -O http://git-osx-installer.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.9.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg
```

Mount:

```
hdiutil attach ./git-1.7.9.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg
```

Install:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/Git\ 1.7.9.1\ Snow\ Leopard\ Intel\ Universal/git-1.7.9.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.pkg -target /
```

Unmount:

```
hdiutil detach /Volumes/Git\ 1.7.9.1\ Snow\ Leopard\ Intel\ Universal/
```

Clean up:

```
rm git-1.7.9.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg
```

Comment: Man, it's a mac! Why would you use five command lines to download and install a simple software. Simple answer: just download and install git!

Comment: One last step was required for me... reboot.

Comment: thanks this is what i call complete and clean answer ... but you forgot one more step to restart the aptana

Comment: Think this is bad to promote this over engineering - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should get github for mac tool from here - http://mac.github.com/

it should allow you to manage repository very easily, and commit, sync operations. And about the error you are geting, it shouldn't matter. try to connect to your git account from terminal and see if you able to connect it or not. as long as it works fine, it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Homebrew - the best Mac Package Manager

[Link](https://brew.sh)

Follow the instructions here - you will need the command line tools from apple too.
Homebrew will open your eyes to many other packages - install PHP / MySQL / Node / Mongo etc by simply

brew install git
brew install a lot of other usefull stuff

and then you can

brew update....

simple - worth the time to explore.