# Heroku Toolbelt - git: Command not found

Tags: facebook, git, api, bash, heroku

I'm working on Mac OSX (10.6.8), and I've just installed the Heroku toolbelt, with hopes of trying to mess around making facebook apps.  I've created a facebook app and according to Heroku's instructions, I should just be able to edit it by entering this into my command line:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:false-title-1234.git -o heroku
```

The Heroku Toolbelt is installed and I am logged in.  But when I run the command above I get this error:

```
-bash: git: command not found
```

I didn't have git before, and apparently I still do not have it.  But I thought it came as part of the Heroku toolbelt?  It seems like, for everyone else on the internet, the git part of it "just works," because I'm not able to find references to problems with the git component of the heroku toolbelt. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install git on your own. Heroku-toolbelt may or may not come with git, but installing git by itself is a relatively simple task.

Here are some instructions for installing git on OSX: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Comment: Thanks!  I just gave that a shot, but it didn't work.  I also tried following the instructions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457102/git-setup-on-mac-error-bash-git-command-not-found , and it also didn't work for me.  They both appear to install git successfully, but I'm still getting the error.  I even tried re-booting my computer just for the hell of it, still 'command not found'.

It occurs to me that I've now tried installing git in 3 different ways (counting Heroku toolbelt) and none of them stuck.  I think there may be a deeper issue.

Comment: Can you tell me what the output of the following command in terminal: sudo find / | grep git

Comment: Oh I see, all of these file names contain "git" somewhere in the name, just as a 3 letter string.  There are a *lot* of files.  Is there anything in particular I should look for?

Comment: You can use these commands in order to find the location of the git executable file. The reason OSX thinks it's not installed is because it's not where it thinks it is. So you have to find out where the executable file *actually* resides, and then create a link to the command in /usr. Then run this command to create a link there: sudo ln -s /directory/you/found/git /usr/bin/

Comment: Finally resolved this issue!  I discovered that the problem was my /usr/local directory was restricted.  I used "sudo chmod 755 /usr/local" to open it, now the git problem has magically disappeard (as well as a similar "heroku: command not found" problem), and that has freed me up to hit an entirely different brick wall.  That will be for another question, another day, thanks very much for the help.